# Android Zoom Gallery Help

Tags: android, gallery, zooming

I really need help please.
I have a comic book type standalone app. The images are flipped using onfling gesture to turn page back and forth
However, I desperately need the ability to zoom for each image/panel.
This is an extended gallery:
Please help me add zoom functionality to this code!
thank you 
Please do not refer me to things already posted here on stackoverflow i have read all of it and it isn't helping me thus far...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         mygallery gallery = (mygallery) findViewById(R.id.thisgallery);

         gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

         gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(main.this, "Page " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

    }

    public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
        int GalItemBg;
        private Context cont;


        private Integer[] Imgid = {
                R.drawable.s1,
                R.drawable.s1a,
                R.drawable.s1b,
                R.drawable.s1b1,
                R.drawable.s1b2,
                R.drawable.s1b3,
                R.drawable.s1c,
                R.drawable.s1s,
                R.drawable.s2,
                R.drawable.s3,
                R.drawable.s4,
                R.drawable.s5,
                R.drawable.s6,
                R.drawable.s7,
                R.drawable.s8,
                R.drawable.s9,
                R.drawable.s10,
                R.drawable.s11,
                R.drawable.s12,
                R.drawable.s13,
                R.drawable.s14,
                R.drawable.s15,
                R.drawable.s16,
                R.drawable.s17,
                R.drawable.s18,
                R.drawable.s19,
                R.drawable.s20,
                R.drawable.s21,
                R.drawable.s22,
                R.drawable.s23,
                R.drawable.s24,
                R.drawable.s25,
                R.drawable.s26,
                R.drawable.s27,
                R.drawable.s28,
                R.drawable.s29,
                R.drawable.s30,
                R.drawable.s31,
                R.drawable.s32,
                R.drawable.s33,
                R.drawable.s34,
                R.drawable.s35,
                R.drawable.s36,
                R.drawable.s37,
                R.drawable.s38,
                R.drawable.s39,
                R.drawable.s40,
                R.drawable.s41,
                R.drawable.s42,
                R.drawable.s43,
                R.drawable.s44,
                R.drawable.s45,
                R.drawable.s46,
                R.drawable.s47,
                R.drawable.s48,
                R.drawable.s49,
                R.drawable.s50,
                R.drawable.s51,
                R.drawable.s52,
                R.drawable.s53,
                R.drawable.s54,
                R.drawable.s55,
                R.drawable.s56,
                R.drawable.s57,
                R.drawable.s58,
                R.drawable.s59,
                R.drawable.s60,
                R.drawable.s61,
                R.drawable.s62,
                R.drawable.s63,
                R.drawable.s64,
                R.drawable.s65,
                R.drawable.s66,
                R.drawable.s67,
                R.drawable.s68,
                R.drawable.s69,
                R.drawable.s70,
                R.drawable.s71,
                R.drawable.s72,
                R.drawable.s73,
                R.drawable.s74,
                R.drawable.s75,
                R.drawable.s76,
                R.drawable.s77,
                R.drawable.s78,
                R.drawable.s79,
                R.drawable.s80,
                R.drawable.s81,
                R.drawable.s82,
                R.drawable.s83,
                R.drawable.s84,
                R.drawable.s85,
                R.drawable.s86,
                R.drawable.s87,
                R.drawable.s88,
                R.drawable.s89,
                R.drawable.s90,
                R.drawable.s91,
                R.drawable.s92,
                R.drawable.s93,
                R.drawable.s94,
                R.drawable.s95,
                R.drawable.s96,
                R.drawable.s97,
                R.drawable.s98,
                R.drawable.s99,
                R.drawable.s100,
                R.drawable.s101,
                R.drawable.s102,
                R.drawable.s103,
                R.drawable.s104,
                R.drawable.s105,
                R.drawable.s106,
                R.drawable.s107,
                R.drawable.s108,
                R.drawable.s109,
                R.drawable.s110,
                R.drawable.s111,
                R.drawable.s112,
                R.drawable.s113,
                R.drawable.s114,
                R.drawable.s115,
                R.drawable.s116,
                R.drawable.s117,
                R.drawable.s118,
                R.drawable.s119,
                R.drawable.s120,
                R.drawable.s121,
                R.drawable.s122,
                R.drawable.s123,
                R.drawable.s124,
                R.drawable.s125,
                R.drawable.s126,
                R.drawable.s127,
                R.drawable.s128,
                R.drawable.s129,
                R.drawable.s130,
                R.drawable.s131,
                R.drawable.s132,
                R.drawable.s133,
                R.drawable.s134,
                R.drawable.s135,
                R.drawable.s136,
                R.drawable.s137,
                R.drawable.s138,
                R.drawable.s139,
                R.drawable.s140,
                R.drawable.s141,
                R.drawable.s142,
                R.drawable.s143,
                R.drawable.s144,
                R.drawable.s145,
                R.drawable.s146,
                R.drawable.s147,
                R.drawable.s148};

        public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
            cont = c;
            TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            typArray.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return Imgid.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

            imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);

            imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(0x0106000d);
            imgView.setLayoutParams(new mygallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            return imgView;
        }
    }
}
```

and the onfling override:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Gallery;




public class mygallery extends Gallery {

    public mygallery(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(ctx, attrSet);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private boolean isScrollingLeft(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2){ 
           return e2.getX() > e1.getX(); 
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
      int kEvent;
      if(isScrollingLeft(e1, e2)){ //Check if scrolling left
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT;
      }
      else{ //Otherwise scrolling right
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT;
      }
      onKeyDown(kEvent, null);
      return true;  
    }

}
```

Comment: I post a link of sample code at [here][1], hopes it can help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268806/android-gallery-with-pinch-zoom

Comment: Have you figured out any solution.if so please share it..@wintermuteai

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android ScaleAnimation class to achieve the zoom effect. The thing is, though, that the animation won't actually change the size/position of the view that it's applied on and that's quite a problem since the hit are of the view you're applying the animation on will always remain the same and so on. However there's no other way to achieve zoom effect AFAIK.(at least in versions of android prior to 3.0).

Comment: Alternatively how can i load each image with a webview so that zoom controls would already be there? please see my code and post help?